# Child elements expanding outside parent element with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have used CSS flex to display two divs side by side which are contained inside a wrapper and I have been trying so that inside `#myClippetWrapper` is where I set the height, so in the child elements of `#myClippetWrapper` I can just set `height: 100%;`.

But as you can see from running the snippet below all of the elements inside `#myClippetWrapper` go outside of the main section, they are all hanging out of the main content div?

I don't want to use `overflow: auto` because I do not want a scroll bar there, I just need the child elements of `#myClippetWrapper` to not be outside of the main section/ div.

```css
main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

#myClippetWrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 700px;
}

#clippetNav {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#codeAndNotesWrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#codeAndNotesWrapper>div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#codeView {
  padding: 10px;
  /*flex: 0 0 40%;*/
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#noteView {
  padding: 10px;
  /*flex: 1;*/
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
}

#codeNotesEditor {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="myClippetWrapper">

    <div id="clippetNav">

    </div>

    <div id="codeAndNotesWrapper">

      <div id="codeView">

      </div>

      <div id="noteView">

        <div id="codeNotesEditor">

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In many cases, flexbox eliminates the need to use percentage heights.

An initial setting of a flex container is `align-items: stretch`. This means that in `flex-direction: row` (like in your code) flex items will automatically expand the full height of the container.

Alternatively, you can use `flex-direction: column` and then apply `flex: 1` to the children, which can also make a flex item expand the full height of the parent.

```css
main {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: red;
}

#myClippetWrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 700px;
}

#clippetNav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #222222;
}

#codeAndNotesWrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#codeAndNotesWrapper>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#codeView {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #222222;
}

#noteView {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #222222;
}

#codeNotesEditor {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="myClippetWrapper">
    <div id="clippetNav"></div>
    <div id="codeAndNotesWrapper">
      <div id="codeView"></div>
      <div id="noteView">
        <div id="codeNotesEditor"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79rat9c1/)

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

To your child elements. This will make the padding show on the inside of the box rather than the outside and will not increase the overall size.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property..

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

#myClippetWrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 700px;
}

#clippetNav {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#codeAndNotesWrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#codeAndNotesWrapper>div {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#codeView {
  padding: 10px;
  /*flex: 0 0 40%;*/
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#noteView {
  padding: 10px;
  /*flex: 1;*/
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
}

#codeNotesEditor {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="myClippetWrapper">

    <div id="clippetNav">



    </div>

    <div id="codeAndNotesWrapper">

      <div id="codeView">



      </div>

      <div id="noteView">

        <div id="codeNotesEditor">

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Is it recommended to have box-sizing set on all elements?

Comment: I've been doing it for a while without issue -- some info here: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: You will most likely run into an issue if you use external html, as it is not standard to do so.

Comment: @StevenJohnston What do you mean by external HTML?

Comment: From a framework, or possibly a solution to a problem you have found here on stackoverflow. But, If you understand how it works (which you should) it definitely not a hard fix.